# How to get Subscription ID from Call Repsonse after successful payment

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

Which is the Subscription ID, I don't mean the Payment Plan ID. I am trying to get the subscription ID after the response from the API call

```
{
  "name": "vbvcomplete",
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "status": "successful",
      "txRef": "1530454208735",
      "amount": "100"
    }
  },
  "respcode": "00",
  "tx": {
    "id": 181165,
    "txRef": "1530454208735",
    "orderRef": "URF_1530454241421_5722735",
    "flwRef": "FLW-MOCK-676ccad060a617d603f64b302fd60a1b",
    "redirectUrl": "N/A",
    "device_fingerprint": "25b4c62b1b20bbb47de5afba12e962e4",
    "settlement_token": null,
    "cycle": "one-time",
    "amount": 100,
    "charged_amount": 100,
    "appfee": 3.25,
    "merchantfee": 0,
    "merchantbearsfee": 1,
    "chargeResponseCode": "00",
    "raveRef": "RV31530454240471C740B66B6A",
    "chargeResponseMessage": "Please enter the OTP sent to your mobile number 080** and email te@rave.com",
    "authModelUsed": "VBVSECURECODE",
    "currency": "USD",
    "IP": "197.210.47.245",
    "narration": "CARD Transaction ",
    "status": "successful",
    "modalauditid": "bcbe53a5c9aaf5dd026f555c66c5da49",
    "vbvrespmessage": "Approved. Successful",
    "authurl": "https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/mockvbvpage?ref=FLW-MOCK-676ccad060a617d603f64b302fd60a1b&code=00&message=Approved. Successful&receiptno=RN1530454241507",
    "vbvrespcode": "00",
    "acctvalrespmsg": null,
    "acctvalrespcode": "RN1530454241507",
    "paymentType": "card",
    "paymentPlan": 239,
    "paymentPage": null,
    "paymentId": "1446",
    "fraud_status": "ok",
    "charge_type": "normal",
    "is_live": 0,
    "createdAt": "2018-07-01T14:10:41.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-01T14:11:09.000Z",
    "deletedAt": null,
    "customerId": 34598,
    "AccountId": 4813,
    "customer": {
      "id": 34598,
      "phone": "0080808808",
      "fullName": "Victor Okonkwo ",
      "customertoken": null,
      "email": "victor_oko2006@yahoo.com",
      "createdAt": "2018-07-01T06:33:51.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-07-01T06:33:51.000Z",
      "deletedAt": null,
      "AccountId": 4813
    },
    "chargeToken": {
      "user_token": "9c2d7",
      "embed_token": "flw-t0-7cd3c21d2617486070f14fe89001d103-m03k"
    },
    "airtime_flag": false
  },
  "respmsg": "Approved. Successful"
}
```

Comment: Reformat json data

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a `POST` request to https://api.ravepay.co/v2/gpx/subscriptions/query

Params for `POST` Request includes:

1. `"seckey"` : This is the merchant secret key
2. `"transaction_id"` :This is the transaction id, it can be gotten in the response from the Transaction verification response data.txid
3. an header with `Content-Type :"application/json"`

Visit https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#list-all-subscriptions to see the documentation for this